# X-coordinates of critical points are independent of m and n

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given a function $f(x)=a(-3x+2)^7-b,$ where a and b are constants that do not equal zero. I am supposed to Show that the x-coordinate(s) of the location(s) of any critical points are independent of a and b. I took the first derivative and second derivative already. I am stuck on how to show this. Thank you!

Comment: By critical point, do you mean a point at which the derivative is zero? I.e. a stationary point? Also, what are $m$ and $n$? You haven't said what they are anywhere, so surely any result you get is independent of them?

Comment: yes, a critical point is a place where the derivative is und or zero.

Comment: What does "und"  mean?

Comment: it means undefined

Comment: what did you get for the first derivative when you worked it out? You are supposed to set this equal to $0$, and solve for $x$. I am pretty sure that this should give you a solution for $x$ that does not depend on $a$ or $b$, which is what the question asks you to show.

Comment: @mathlover the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) = -3a$ is very dependent upon $a$ and independent of $b$.
There are no critical points, points x for which $f'(x) = 0$, as $a$ is nonzero.
It makes no difference if $b$ is zero.
So as there are no critical points, their location,
namely nowhere, is independent of any nonzero $a$.

By the power of the lucky $7$,
$f'(x) = -21ax(-3x + 2)^6 = 0  $
which for nonzero $a$ is equivalent to $x(-3x + 2)^6 = 0.  $

So the critical points are independent of $b$ and nonzero $a$.
Why second derivatives?
Are you looking for local minimums/maximums, inflection points?

Comment: Hey! The question has been edited. It was missing a power of $7$, so now it probably can have turning points.

Comment: @JohnDoe.  See edit.